# Session Continually Times out when Accessing SuperMicro IPMI via Cloudflare Tunnel

Tags: cloudflare, ipmi, supermicro, tunnel

I have a SuperMicro X12dpi-N6 motherboard system that is currently running Ubuntu 22.04 Server. In order to support remote maintenance, I configured a [cloudflare tunnel](https://www.cloudflare.com/products/tunnel/) that would allow me to access the `IPMI` site remotely (we do not use the default credentials). `cloudflared` is running on a separate machine and has not given us any issues with the tunnels that it is running. No TLS Verify was enabled for this tunnel.

[image: Machine Information]

However, when I attempt to login, I repeatedly get the following error that blocks me from accessing the site and forces me to attempt to login again.

```
Your session has timed out. You will need to open a new session.
```

[image: A browser pop-up saying that your session has timed out]

After speaking with the SuperMicro support team, I was advised to turnoff session timeout.[image: The SuperMicro IPMI timeout interface.]

But after making this change, I continued to run into the session issues. Is it possible that this is due to a TLS/SSL issue?  How can I make it so that I can access the IPMI interface remotely via a `cloudflare` tunnel?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it applies for your case as well, but for me it helped to unset the `Authorization` HTTP header on the reverse proxy. Any frontend authentication *must not* be passed to the SuperMicro IPMI, otherwise it seems to confuse the IPMI firmware. Note that I don't know what Cloudflare does or does not do, nor how to configure.

Comment: I did play around with Authorization headers while I was dealing with this problem, but I was ultimately not able to find a solution with Cloudflare.  The solution I use now is tailscale's function that allows you to expose private subnets.  As a backup, I also have an L2TP VPN setup via an edge router.